# Simple REST API for use with Ext JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, rest, extjs

I would like to start learning **Ext JS**. Seems to be an interesting and powerful Framework.

As I can imagine to replace some very old **PHP/MySQL web applications**, I would like to start with an Ext JS example with a working MySQL connection. I thought of REST, but that's just my idea, not a must. Happy to hear other solutions.

So the next idea which I had was, to find a simple **REST API in PHP**. Seems it doesn't have to be very complicated. Just read DB records, update, create and sometimes delete data as well. Few users. Intranet environment, so limited different browsers. Limited security requirements. To me it seems, something like that should already exist and be working quite stable.

*And this is where I got stuck.*

My Ext JS Example is here: 
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/classic/restful/restful.html

The two best simple REST APIs which I found are:

1) https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

2) https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api

But 1) is only for reading from the DB, 2) doesn't work properly, I can write but reading doesn't work. The Output is different to 1).

I would really like to focus on Javascript and UI instead of understanding fully REST/SOAP/CRUD and whatever. I just need to write data to a DB read it from there. Does it have to be so complicated? Can someone give me a hint for a simple and lightweight solution?

Additionally, I am wondering why

- so many places where someone talks about REST, but the protocol seems not to be defined clearly.
- such an exciting and sophisticated Framework like Ext JS exists. But there's hardly any information on how to do the backend. (It simply doesn't work without the backend).

Comment: `so many places where someone talks about REST, but the protocol seems not to be defined clearly.` what do you mean by that? Also, this question seems to be too broad. It might need to be split into few.

Comment: To me it seems not to be defined clearly if these two APIs which I found deliver different output formats.

Comment: I don't think it's too broad. Main question could be answered like: take the REST API from xyz and configure it with abc and it works.... The two additional questions are just fiddling around in my head.

Comment: REST API is a very broad subject. Every REST API is different, which is why someone said in the comments that your question is too broad. It seems that your lack of understanding of REST API causes you to believe your question is narrow when it isn't.

Comment: I'm the author of both scripts. Script 1 is not only reading from the DB. Script 2 is working fine for many people (and the tests run fine too). You also posted this question as an issue to Github on my repository and you are not responding. I still would love to help you out.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Your first script is of course not only reading. I used your script in my answer with very slight modifications. I hope it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the REST API mentioned in the first link is nearly sufficient for the Ext JS example. It needed only a few minor changes and everything works.
See [here](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/) for more details.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

// get the HTTP method, path and body of the request
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

// connect to the mysql database
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'table');
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');

// retrieve the table and key from the path
$table = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
$key = array_shift($request)+0;

// escape the columns and values from the input object
$columns = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_keys($input));
$values = array_map(function ($value) use ($link) {
  if ($value===null) return null;
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($link,(string)$value);
},array_values($input));

// build the SET part of the SQL command
$set = '';
for ($i=0;$i<count($columns);$i++) {
  $set.=($i>0?',':'').'`'.$columns[$i].'`=';
  $set.=($values[$i]===null?'NULL':'"'.$values[$i].'"');
}

// create SQL based on HTTP method
switch ($method) {
  case 'GET':
    $sql = "select * from `$table`".($key?" WHERE id=$key":''); break;
  case 'PUT':
    $sql = "update `$table` set $set where id=$key"; break;
  case 'POST':
    $sql = "insert into `$table` set $set"; break;
  case 'DELETE':
    $sql = "delete from `$table` where id=$key"; break;
}

// excecute SQL statement
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

// die if SQL statement failed
if (!$result) {
  http_response_code(404);
  die(mysqli_error());
}

// print results, insert id or affected row count
if ($method == 'GET') {
  if (!$key) echo '[';
  for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++) {
    echo ($i>0?',':'').json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result));
  }
  if (!$key) echo ']';
} elseif ($method == 'POST') {
  echo '{ "success":true, "data":[ { "id":'.mysqli_insert_id($link).' }]}';
} else {
  echo mysqli_affected_rows($link);
}

// close mysql connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nils .. I am wondering how you got on.
We started this exact process around the same. We ended up working with the SLIM php framework to build a nice REST api. I'd recommend it.